# Can Foundation be captured in $\mathcal L(\omega_1,\omega)$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, infinitary-logic

Working in $\mathcal L_{\omega_1, \omega}$, can Foundation be captured?

My idea is to formalize a theory where all of its models are the well founded pointwise definable models of $\sf ZFC$. I attempt to formalize it as:

$\textbf{Foundation: } \\\forall x: \neg [ \bigwedge_{n \in \omega}   (\exists v_0,..,\exists v_n: \bigwedge_{i \in n} (v_{i+1} \in v_i) \land v_0 \in x)] $

In English: for every set $x$ it is not the case that for every finite size there is a descending membership set from $x$ of that size.

This way all sets would be truly well founded.

So we add all axioms of $\sf ZF$ written as usual in $\mathcal L_{\omega,\omega}$, and finally add the definability axiom written in $\mathcal L_{\omega_1, \omega}$, which is:

$\textbf{ Axiom of Definability: } \forall x  D(x)$,

Where "$D$" is defined as:

$$Dx \iff  \bigvee  x= \{ y \mid \Phi \}$$

where $\Phi$ range over all formulas in $\mathcal L_{\omega, \omega}$ in which only the symbol "$y$" occurs free, and the symbol "$y$" never occurs bound.

> Are all models of this theory well founded!

If that works, then we have all models of this theory countable, all pointwise definable, and all are well founded. And I think that all ought to be arithmetically sound.

> But, do all models of this theory prove exactly the same $\mathcal L_{\omega, \omega}$ set theoretic sentences.

My point is that every set theoretic sentence in $\mathcal L_{\omega, \omega}$ can be written arithmetically, then if this theory captures standard arithmetic, then it cannot prove opposing arithmetical sentences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Foundation axiom does not assert that there is no infinite descending sequence, but rather merely rules out sets at infinite set-theoretic rank. For example, if $x=\omega$, then we can find for every $n$ a descending $\in$ sequence of length $n$.

You can formulate well-foundedness in $L_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$ by saying directly that there is no infinite $\in$-descending sequence. But this is not possible in $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$, by a result due to Morley.

Comment: More generally, well-foundedness is not expressible in $L_{\infty,\omega}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek What is the best/easiest way to see that?

Comment: It’s not supposed to be easy to see. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/#6 tells me it was proved by Karp [1965] and Lopez-Escobar [1966].

Comment: The problem of $L_{∞,ω}$ was asked by Mostowski, Lopez-Escobar solved it by first finding that the Hanf number of $L_{κ,ω}$ is less or equal to $\beth_{(2^{κ})^+}$, then assume $φ∈L_{κ^+,ω}$ express well-ordering (we can assume it is a single sentence, if we require a theory $T⊆L_{λ,ω}$ we can just take $κ=\max(|T|,λ)$ and let $φ$ be the conjunction of $T$) then they construct a (quite complicated) sentence $ψ∈L_{κ^+,ω}$ such that ordinals $(α,∈;...)$ does not satisfy $ψ$ if $α>\beth_{2^{2^{2^{κ}}}}$ but there exists $α≥\beth_{(2^{κ^+})^+}$ that satisfy this sentece

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Perhaps another way to see this through Hanf numbers is by building indiscernibles.  Morley's Omitting Types Theorem (which I recently learned is due to Chang in the uncountable case) says that if $\phi \in L_{\kappa, \omega}$ has models of size (cofinal in) $\beth_{(2^\kappa)^+}$, then it has arbitrarily large models.  The proof goes by building a blueprint $\Phi$ that builds model $EM_\tau(T, \Phi)$ of $\phi$ with $I$ as indiscernibles.  You can modify this to build the indiscernibles in whatever definable set you like (or more) as long as the definable set...

Comment: ...is sufficiently big.  So take your hopefuly definition $\phi$, and we may as well make the well-ordered bit some predicate $(P, <)$.  If $\phi$ has models were $(P, <)$ has size (cofinal in) the Hanf number, build a blueprint $\phi$ so the indiscernibles are in $P$.  This will contradict the well-orderedness by, e.g., plugging in an I with lots of automorphisms.